# Copy files from sub-directories to base directory in hdfs using spark/scala

Tags: scala, file, apache-spark, hdfs, subdirectory

I have folders created under a base hdfs directory everytime a job runs.
And under each folder there are .dat files.

I need to copy the .dat files to my base directory using scala and archive the sub-directories

For example. 
Base directory:-  /user/srav/
Sub-directories:- /user/srav/20190101
                  /user/srav/20180101

I have .dat files in my sub-directories /user/srav/20190101/test1.dat, /user/srav/20180101/test2.dat
I need to copy them under /user/srav/ and archive the 20190101, 20180101 folders. Please suggest on how we could implement this using spark/scala (spark ver 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [hadoop fs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html). Something like this:

```
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

  val conf2 = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
  val fs = FileSystem.get(conf2)

  val srcs = Array("/user/srav/20190101","/user/srav/20180101").map(new Path(_))
  val dst = new Path("/user/srav/")

  fs.moveFromLocalFile(srcs,dst)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick post Chlebek,  The sub-directories inside the base directory are dynamic. We need to check if sub-directories exist or not and then move files inside those directories (not the sub-directory).